# сортировка массива пар (x, y) по y в Python

Tags: python, сортировка

Я имею массив `x` и `y`, где `y = f(x)`. Требуется отсортировать эти пары по `y`.

Сейчас я это делаю так: завожу два `list`, делаю вручную сортировку по `y`, и хвостом при этом тяну `x`.

Как это лучше сделать средствами языка? Или еще как?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно использовать `sort` с сортировкой по ключу. Примерно так:

```
lst = [(1, 6), (2, 5), (3, 4), (8, 3), (7, 2)]
lst.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
print(lst)
```

Вывод:

```
[(7, 2), (8, 3), (3, 4), (2, 5), (1, 6)]
```